# How to disable Ctrl-Alt-Delete to reboot the VM hosted in a Vmware Esx Server?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vsphere-client

I have a Linux VM hosted on a Vmware ESx Server5.5, in the production environment. And I need to disable the Ctrl-Alt-Delete option. So that While working on the Console option in the vSphere Client on that VM. Ctrl-Alt-Delete should not reboot the VM.

How can I achieve that? I could not find any Power Settings or Keyboard settings for this. Even if there are other ways within the Linux VM machine configuration changes, that should be fine.

Comment: You'll need to configure the Linux VM to trap the key combination - what distribution are we talking about?

Comment: @pauska I am using the RHEL VM customized in the OVA format as per my need.

Answer (score 1):

You have to fix this at the Linux level. And that is going to depend on your specific Linux system's version.

For a virtual machine, though, I'd try to avoid working on the VMware console. It's not a good user experience.

Please see: [Isn't Ctrl-Alt-Delete on Linux *really* dangerous?](https://serverfault.com/questions/614051/isnt-ctrl-alt-delete-on-linux-really-dangerous)